# What's the difference between Texas Instruments V62/06623-01XE and MAX3232MDBREP?

Tags: texas-instruments

I'm using a MAX3232 but given different production codes with the same package (V62/06623-01XE, MAX3232MDBREP), is there any difference between them?

Can the two be used as substitutes for each other?
[Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232-ep.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1684217800033&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fmax3232-ep) check out page 8
[www.ti.com/product/MAX3232-EP](http://www.ti.com/product/MAX3232-EP)

[image]

Comment: I click the link and can't see anything resembling your screenshot. Is the link correct? What should we click to see that?

Comment: @Justme I edited the post,thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two parts are the same.

As it seems, you can't order V62/06623-01XE any longer. TI probably updated the part identifier at some point.

[image]

<sup>Source: https://www.ti.com/product/MAX3232-EP/part-details/MAX3232MDBREP</sup>

Comment: thank you I did not notice that.